# panel data model

Tags: regression

Good Morning,
I have a doubt.
I am doing a panel data model to calculate the benchmarking of some companies in the sector.
is there any test that I can apply to know if I use fixed or random effects?
I'm using eviews.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

[Hausman Test Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Wu%E2%80%93Hausman_test)

and here:

[Hausman Test in Eviews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ErACP5HD1Y)

Comment: andré, você é brasileiro?

Comment: Sim, @LarissaScalco

Comment: Tudo bem, mas só posso ajudar em algo pontual.